# MongoDB aggregation: conditional aggregation stages

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Is it possible to have conditional aggregation stages depending on returned variables from aggregation?

For example

```
User.aggregate([
    // if user has a property verified that returns true run aggregation pipeline
    // one. Else run aggregation pipeline 2.
])
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Of course you can, by using [$facet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/) with 2 different pipelines, and put for each first stage a $match stage with your property verification.

Here's an example of such a query:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$facet": {
      "avgSteps": [
        {
          "$match": {
            hasCar: false
          }
        },
        {
          $project: {
            steps: {
              $avg: "$walks.steps"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "sumDistance": [
        {
          "$match": {
            hasCar: true
          }
        },
        {
          $project: {
            sumKm: {
              $sum: "$travels.distance"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      
    }
  }
])
```

[You can test it here.](https://mongoplayground.net/p/xZR8Tk9aGHJ)

Comment: Sometimes when I ask a question on this site I get surprised. I honestly thought I would have to look for a work around. But then, I don’t. Because someone has a solution. And the solutions are most of the time simple yet effective. This platform has given me so much value. Your answer is much appreciated.